# Php-fpm: abnormal cpu usage over time

Tags: php, apache, memcached, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running apache (2.4.29) + php-fpm (php 7.2) + memcached on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS VM (VM Ware vSphere Hypervisor) with 16 vcore (2Ghz) and 16GB of RAM.

Mysql 5.7 on separate server and php-fpm setting as:

pm = dynamic pm.max_children = 256 pm.start_servers = 110 pm.min_spare_servers = 32 pm.max_spare_servers = 150

(which is quite over provisioned)

Max RAM usage ever less then 15% ( about 2.5GB)

Since 3 month I'm fighting with a strange behaviour : global cpu usage increase over time doing the same process (mostly php-fpm) till usage exceeds 100% (sometimes 150%) causing the server became unavailable (and generating a lot of alert events on vsphere dashboard!)

This behaviour require typically 3/4 days : the first day everything is fine and cpu usage are below 40% then next day it gains 10/20% more until, on the third or fourth day, it exceed 100% and the only solution is rebooting the VM.

What I see is that every day php-fpm process request more cpu!

The amount of connected users are always the same every day and also the amount of requests / min doesn't change from day to day. Looking with top I see always the same number of process (about 450), no zombie. No memory leak (always below 15% of active usage).

I firstly check for Mysql as bottleneck sources but Mysql replies fast and the VM which hosted it is alway below 30% of global cpu usage.

Then I carefully analyzed every available logs (apache access and error logs and php-fpm logs) looking for something strange but I haven't found anything strange: always the same routes! no trace of DOS attacks or request overloads.

Looking system logs (syslog, messages, etc.) leads to nothing.

Since I saw the problem I've never updated the OS (which is quite updated): vmware tools are updated and no php sources variations has been made.

I've tried restarting single services (php-fpm, apache, memcached) to find the origin of this absurd behaviour but it seem the the only solution is rebooting the VM.

It seems like the resource leaked is CPU!

I tried to contact the provider where the VMs are hosted but (obviously) they don't detect any problems on the node.. paradoxically it is enough to restart the VM every 3 days and there are no problems... absurd!

Any suggestions will be very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can try setting the [pm.max_requests](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) configuration option to something that ensures the processes get recycled every few hours to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will suspect this could be a possible solution. What prevents me to do this earlier is that no memory leaks were detected. If I don't mind main advantage of this options is preventing memory leaks

Comment: Please post your complete TEXT php-fpm configuration files for analysis.  You only have 16 cores and may be 'overdriving' processes with values listed.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide Performance Tuning suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck : thanks for your clarification. At moment I started with better php-fpm configuration which is:   pm.max_children = 256 
pm.start_servers = 64
pm.min_spare_servers = 32
pm.max_spare_servers = 64
pm.max_requests = 1000  then I'll collect the information you asked. thanks

Comment: How do you think 16 cores will support this number of activities you have requested?  What are you leaving for MySQL to use to support client tasks?

Comment: Yes, they're enough to handle all usual activities, they were for a long time and not significant app variations were added recently. The amount of incoming requests are always the same (no evidence of dos attack). MySQL is hosted on another servers with reasonable resources (never over 40% of load) , no particular slow query. We're using heavily memcached to avoid unnecessary MySQL data requests. It seems that lowering php-fpm parameters gives some benefits: I'll keep monitoring the system

Comment: Any chance you will be able to post Additional information requested to allow Workload Analysis for your server's activities?

Comment: @WilsonHauck : Host provider contacted us to notify some problems on the node where out VM is hosted. It seems that problems was related to infrastrutture updates! (previously they told us they didn't found any problems...) Now the workload is reasonable so the problem seems solved. Thanks for your precious suppoprt.

Comment: Thanks for the news that your Host has helped you achieve a reasonable workload.  They are a very important component, required for success.  To improve performance, contact us.